# in oracle what is the deference between raising exception and reraising

Tags: oracle, exception

in oracle what is the deference between raising exception and reraising exception 'with simple example please' and what is the deference between exception and normal if statement that print error if it happens?

Comment: You re-raise an error to give the handle back to the caller. See few examples here https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/

Answer (score 1):

One big difference between raising an exception vs. re-raising an exception is that with a `RAISE;` the original error message is preserved, e.g. (this is a contrived example, hopefully you get the idea):

```
create table t (x varchar2(1));

begin
  insert into t values ('aa');
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    raise;
end;

ORA-12899: value too large for column "XXSPS"."T"."X" (actual: 2, maximum: 1)
```

vs.

```
declare
  value_too_large exception;
  pragma exception_init (value_too_large, -12899);
begin
  insert into t values ('aa');
exception
  when value_too_large then
    raise value_too_large;
end;

ORA-12899: value too large for column  (actual: , maximum: )
```

In the 2nd case, we raise the "value_too_large" exception which has no reference back to the original exception that had the column name or length information.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside an exception handler in an exception section, you can re-raise the exception that “got you there” by issuing an unqualified RAISE statement as follows:

RAISE;
Since you do not specify an exception, the PL/SQL runtime engine re-raises the current exception (whose error number would be returned by a call to the SQLCODE function).

Here is an example of using raise in this way:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      send_error_to_pipe (SQLCODE);
      RAISE;
END;
```